# How to place 3D objects in a scene?

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering

I'm developing a simple rendering engine as a pet project. 
So far I'm able to load geometry data from Wavefront .obj files and render them onscreen separately. I know that vertex coordinates stored in these files are defined in Model space and to place them correctly in the scene I need to apply Model-to-world transform matrix to each vertex position (am I even correct here?).

But how do I define those matrices for each object? Do i need to develop a separate tool for scene composition, in which I will move objects around and the "tool" will calculate appropriate Model-to-world matrices based on translations, rotations an so on?

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, guys! Would you be so kind to explain them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the "Scene Graph" data structure. It's essentially a tree, where nodes (may) define their transformations relative to their parent. Think of it this way. Each of your fingers moves relative to your hand. Moving your hand, rotating or scaling it also involves doing the same transformation on your fingers.

It is therefore beneficial to base all these relative transformations on one another as relative ones, and combine trhem to determine the overall transformation of each individual part of your model. As such you don't just define the direct model to view transformation, but rather a transformation from each part to its parent.

This saves having to define a whole bunch of transformations yourself, which are in the vast majority of cases similarly in the way I described anyway. As such you save yourself a lot of work by representing your models/scene in this manner.

Each of these relative transformations is usually a 4x4 affine transformation matrix. Combining these is just a matter of multiplying them together to obtain the combination of all of them.

[A description of Scene Graphs](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/scenegraph/)

In order to animate objects within a scene graph, you need to specify transformations relative to their parent in the tree. For instance, spinning wheels of a car need to rotate relative to the car's chassis. These transformations largely depend on what kind of animations you'd like to show.

So I guess the answer to your question is "mostly yes". You do need to define transformations for every single object in your scene if things are going to look good. However, orgasnising the scene into a tree structure makes this process a lot easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I guess eventually I'll have to write a piece of software for manipulating these graphs in a convenient way.

Comment: @ПавелМуратов: What you do for a first implementation is to create a scenenode class, which contains a transformation matrix and a list of children. You then construct a scenenode depending on the hierarchy of your scene. You keep a reference to one root node. Each frame, you first update the scene graph. Here you traverse every node of the tree, changing any transformation necessary. Remember that each transformation represents the transformation of that particular node relative to its parent. For example: in the case of a solar system, a moon describes how it moves relative to its planet,

Comment: (continued) and a planet describes how it orbits around the sun. Once you have calculated your transformations, you can go through the whole scene graph a second time, and render each object with the transformation matrix you previously calculated for that node.

Comment: Many thanks, man! This is a valuable information for a newbie like myself.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the creation of those matrices what you have to do is to export a scene from an authoring package.
That software can be the same you used to model the objects in the first place, Maya, Lightwave...
Right now you have your objects independent of each other.

So, using the package of your choice, either find a file format allowing you to export a scene you would have made by positioning each of your meshes where you want them, like FBX or GLTF or make your own.

Either way there is a scene structure, containing models, transforms, lights, cameras, everything you want in your engine.

After that you have to parse that structure.
You'll find here some explanations regarding how you could architect that:
https://nlguillemot.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/opengl-renderer-design/

Good luck,

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Will definitely look into the article you proposed.